# «Зена — королева воинов»: двусоставное предложение или конструкция с приложением?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор, заголовок

В названии сериала «Зена — королева воинов» «Зена» подлежащее, а «королева воинов» сказуемое? Или здесь другие синтаксические конструкции (например, приложение после тире)?

Answer (score 1):

Может сначала показаться, что тире тут означает пропуск связки:

> **Тире, прежде всего, означает пропуски — пропуск связки в сказуемом**, пропуск члена предложения в неполных предложениях и в
> предложениях с нулевым сказуемым, пропуск противительных союзов. Тире
> как бы компенсирует эти пропущенные слова, сохраняет принадлежащее им
> место, например:
>
> *«Солотча — извилистая, неглубокая река»* (К. Паустовский); — пропуск связки; 
> …
>
> [[Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5)]

«Зена» — подлежащее;
«королева» — сказуемое;
«воинов» — определение.

Пропущенная связка:

«Зена *есть* королева воинов».

---

Однако, данное предложение, **не является утверждением**. Это не дача определения тому, кто такая Зена.

---

*«Зена — королева воинов»* — название фильма. В данном случае «королева воинов» – это пояснение для зрителей, кто такая Зена.  Таким образом, «королева воинов» – это приложение.

Приложения выделяются тире в следующих случаях:

> 1. **приложение носит пояснительный характер**, перед тире можно
>    поставить или стоят слова: а именно, то есть. *В дальнем углу
>    светилось желтое пятно – огонь в окне квартиры Серафимы, пристроенной
>    к стене конюшни.* 
>    …
>     3) **приложение заканчивает предложение**.
>    В вазе стояли ромашки – желтоглазые цветы.
>
> [[mogu-pisat.ru](https://mogu-pisat.ru/spravochnik/?wiki_name=%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85)]

Название фильма: «Зена — королева воинов» = Зена, *то есть (иными словами)* королева воинов.

---

В оригинале фильм называется: “Xena: Warrior Princess”.

Двоеточие указывает на приложение.

> Often a colon can be used to introduce an appositive that renames or
> defines some part of the information that comes before the colon. In
> this case, the colon acts as a substitute for a word like i.e. or a
> phrase like that is to say.
>
> Часто двоеточие может использоваться для введения приложения, которое
> **называет дргими словами или даёт определение некоторой части информации, идущей перед двоеточием**. В этом случае двоеточие действует как заменитель
> слова или сочетания слов по смыслу подобных «то есть».
>
> [[sana.aalto.fi](http://sana.aalto.fi/awe/punctuation/colons/2colon.html)]

---

Оригинальное название подтверждает, что по смыслу «принцесса воинов» — это именно приложение.